# run eunit test from console using erl -noshell

Tags: erlang

I wanted to run the following eunit test command from console

```
eunit:test([test_module, [verbose]).
```

I tried this, but seems not working
erl -noshell -pa ./ebin -s eunit test test_module verbose -init stop

```
~/uid_server$erl -noshell -pa ./ebin -s eunit test test_module verbose -init stop
undefined
*** test module not found ***
::test_module

=======================================================
  Failed: 0.  Skipped: 0.  Passed: 0.
One or more tests were cancelled.
```

Do you know how to pass not a simple arguments properly from console?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your parameters look wrong. This should work:

```
erl -noshell -pa ebin -eval "eunit:test(test_module, [verbose])" -s init stop
```

`-s` can only run functions without arguments by specifying the module and function name (for example `init` and `stop` to execute `init:stop()`).

You can also pass one list to a function of arity 1 like this:

```
-s foo bar a b c
```

would call

```
foo:bar([a,b,c])
```

All the parameters are passed as a list of atoms only (even when you try to use some other characters, such as numbers, they are converted to atoms).

So since you want to pass two params and not only atoms if you want to run `eunit:test/2` you'd have to use `-eval` which takes a string containing Erlang code as an argument. All `-eval` and `-s` functions are executed sequentially in the order they are defined.

Also, make sure you have your test code in ./ebin as well (otherwise write `-pa ebin test_ebin` where `test_ebin` is where your test code is).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use rebar...

- Get rebar by cd'ing to your project directory and typing the following:

  `curl http://cloud.github.com/downloads/basho/rebar/rebar -o rebar`

  `chmod u+x rebar`
- Add the following to your module under test, right after last export:

  `-ifdef(TEST).`

  `-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").`

  `-endif.`
- Next, add your tests at the bottom of your module, wrapped in an ifdef like so:

  `-ifdef(TEST).`

  `simple_test() ->`

  `?assertNot(true).`

  `-endif.`
- Lastly, run rebar from your shell like so:

  `./rebar compile eunit`

Answer (score 1):

you can try quote parameters instead of listing.
erl -noshell -pa ./ebin -s eunit test "test_module verbose" -init stop

Answer (score 1):

More than eight years passed since the question, but there's still a nice solution not mentioned in the previous answers.

Once you are using EUnit, you can leverage from some of it's "automagic" features. One of them is an automatic export of the `test/0` function, containing all the tests for the module.

So, if you are writing your tests alongside with the source code in the same module, all you have to do is:

```
$ erl -noshell -run your_module test -run init stop
```

If you are writing the tests in a separated, dependent module (as you should), you have to point to that module:

```
$ erl -noshell -run your_module_tests test -run init stop
```

All this will work fine, but the test won't be run in verbose mode as the OP required, but this is simple to solve with the `EUNIT` environment variable set to `verbose`.

Final version:

```
$ EUNIT=verbose erl -noshell -run your_module_tests test -run init stop
```

Have fun with Erlang and EUnit!

Answer (score 0):

I use this script: https://github.com/lafka/dotconfig/blob/master/bin/eunit-module to run eunit on specific modules.

**Example:**

```
eunit-module <module> src ebin -I deps
```

*That will do a couple of things:*

- Arg #2 is the directory where .erl resides
- Arg #3 is the directory to output the compiled .beam
- Arg #4++ is all the additional paths to add to your code path
- Using -I specifies additional code paths AND  where to look for files referenced with -include_lib